# I have change custom user model in middle of project so admin page is giving me this error But my Api is working fine only admin page has problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K83u.png)i have change my custom user model in middle of the project so iam getting such error inside table which is having foreign relationship

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\tagon-lucky_wheel_api-OldNbhB5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
   __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you share your models? Looks like a `__str__` method on one of your models is not returning a string

Comment: Its been resolved